# Adding more AND expressions to a query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following function:

```
def getUsers(flagged):
    if flagged:
        users = session.query(User).filter(User.flagged == True)
    else:
        users = session.query(User)

    return users
```

Which means, if flagged is True, the query only returns users with flagged set to True, otherwise all users are returned. Now I want to add a second parameter, points, when set it should return those users with higher points than specified:

```
def getUsers(flagged, points):
    if points is not None:
        if flagged:
            users = session.query(User).filter(User.points > points, User.flagged == True)
        else:
            users = session.query(User).filter(User.points > points)
    else:
        if flagged:
            users = session.query(User).filter(User.flagged == True)
        else:
            users = session.query(User)

    return users
```

As you see, this becomes more and more of a mess. If this would have been pure SQL I would have built up a string by simply appending more AND clauses as needed, but how do I do that if I want to use sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain `.filter()` calls:

```
def getUsers(flagged, points):
    users = session.query(User)
    if points is not None:
        users = users.filter(User.points > points)
    if flagged:
        users = users.filter(User.flagged == True)
    return users
```

Each `.filter()` call returns a refined query object. You can add on more filters as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like that:

```
def getUsers(flagged, points):
    conditions = []
    if points is not None:
        if flagged:
            conditions.append(and_(User.points > points, User.flagged == True))
        else:
            conditions.append(User.points > points)
    else:
        if flagged:
            conditions.append(User.flagged == True)
    users = session.query(User).filter(conditions)

    return users
```